# Tagging an equation with a tikz duck

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzducks

I would like to label and equation with a tikz duck from the tikzducks package and refer back to it later, like so:
[image]

The obvious solution:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\section*{Question 1}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item

\[a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2} \tag{$\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \duck
    \end{tikzpicture}$} \label{C}\]

From equation \(\eqref{C}\), $b^{2} = c^{2} - a^{2}$.

\end{enumerate}
```

gives me the error:
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. However when I put the duck elsewhere in the image, I do not get this error, the document compiles and I get to see my duck (quack)!

(I might add that it doesn't matter whether or not the tikzpicture environment is placed inside math mode or not.)

I can't seem to find a way to stop this error from happening.

Thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: Please extend your example to something that ought to compile. There is no document class, no `document` env. Also `\(\eqref{C}\),` does not make any sense. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have no issues once I added something that supports `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]`

Comment: Sorry I am a new user, should I copy and paste my whole preamble or just enough so that it complies?

Comment: This is a good guide: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that, you should always seek to provide something that others can just copy and test as is without having to add something. What you post should also be self contained (no images or files we don't have access to, one can always use the images that comes with the `mwe` package, see CTAN). It should also be minimal, thus only the package that are relevant for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will read this for next time I post. The comment below solved my problem when I use xparse instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\NewDocumentCommand\ducktag{}
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \duck
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Question 1}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item 

\[a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2} \tag{\ducktag} \label{C} \]

From equation \eqref{C}, $b^{2} = c^{2} - a^{2}$.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also add an argument for options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\NewDocumentCommand\ducktag{m}
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \duck[#1]
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Question 1}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item

\[a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2} \tag{\ducktag{}} \label{B} \]

From equation \eqref{C}, $b^{2} = c^{2} - a^{2}$.

\item 

\[a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2} \tag{\ducktag{body=blue}} \label{C} \]

From equation \eqref{C}, $b^{2} = c^{2} - a^{2}$.

\item 

\[a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2} \tag{\ducktag{body=red}} \label{D} \]

From equation \eqref{B}, \eqref{C} and \eqref{D} $b^{2} = c^{2} - a^{2}$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Paulo will be so proud

Comment: Somehow this fixes things. Thanks.

Comment: @DamianLin if you want to refer to a tag, it has to be written to the aux-file. And this means that the command must be "robust". `\NewDocumentCommand` creates such robust commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's strange, the only thing I needede to make it work was adding `enumerate`. I did not need to make a robust command

Comment: @daleif oh, you are right, it works then too, I corrected the enumerate error later, after I created already the robust command (but I think it is a good idea anyway not to put large bunches of code inside \tag).

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME